# Install Nodejs for V8 Rails to use Less

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to install Bootstrap for Rails, but i always got this error:

```
Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/less-2.4.0/lib/less/java_sc
ript/v8_context.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- v8 (LoadError)
```

To avoid this problem i installed nodejs and added this line in config/boot:

```
ENV['EXECJS_RUNTIME'] = 'Node'
```

So when i restart my webrich server i see on public indey that the javascript runtime now is nodejs. Then i reapeted the installation of twitter bootstrap but get the same error. I use Rails 4.0 and hope that somebody has an advice for me? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For Javascript runtime in Rails : Dont use the 'therubyracer' or 'execjs' in your gem files.

First remove those in ur Gemfile and and Remove Gemfile.lock.

After that do this following installation for nodejs.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

I am considering your environment as ubuntu/linux. So for that use above command

And Bundle your app.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `execjs` is a dependency of Rails - you kinda have to use it. Giving Linux-specific instructions isn't going to help the asker either - he's on Windows.

Comment: I think there is no need of adding this line in config/boot:  ENV['EXECJS_RUNTIME'] = 'Node'

Comment: Insttalling nodejs on windows may help him. I have faced this issue in past. It may help you .

Comment: You're still not reading - he said he's already installed nodejs.